# Performance of adding and removing values from HashSet<T> versus checking a flag in a Dictionary<T, bool>

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, hashset

In my code, I want to check whether if a task (in an other thread) is currently running or not.

I was considering using a `Dictionary<String, bool>`, and checking the boolean value. However, since I don't know all the possible tasks at startup, I will have to populate this Dictionary on the fly when the task is started for the first time and query it like this:

```
Boolean status;
if (_tasks.TryGetValue(lockName, out  status))
{
    return status;
}
return false;
```

Since, instead of having this bool, the mere existence of the entry can be informative, I am considering using `Hashset<String>` and adding/removing values instead of setting the flag.

```
return _tasks.Contains(name)
```

I am wondering which of these two approaches would yield the best results. I expect approximately the same number of write operations than reads.

Comment: I think Guffa is right here but in case it *really* matters you should consider setting up a simple experiment and measure the timing of both - it should not be terrible hard and you get reliable facts this way

Comment: Agreed, and I'm doing it at the same time. But I thought this would be a good question to ask (for Google search posterity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be any significant difference.

Both uses a hash lookup to check for the key, which is close to an O(1) operation.